# jQuery AJAX GET/POST request returns 404 in error handler, but valid response is sent from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

The Problem: I send GET or POST request with jQuery.ajax and get an error handler triggered with 404. The thing is, I have used a sniffer to check an answer from server and it is a valid 200 response with a correct JSON (returned by Python json.dumps).
And something weird: after this call ends up with 404 a browser reloads the page.

Everything lives in the same domain (and subdomain too).

jQuery call:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/m/auth/login", data: {x: "y"},
success: function(result) {}, error: function(xhr) {}, dataType: "json"});
```

Response as seen by sniffer with payload decompressed:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate\r\n
Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.000018\r\n
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=71 cpu_ms=0\r\n
Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 21:04:36 GMT\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT\r\n
Server: Google Frontend\r\n
Content-Length: 80\r\n
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,80:quic\r\n
\r\n
{"reason": {"password": "missing", "email": "missing"}, "error": "argument"}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the series of events the client is experiencing here. The client loads a page from App Engine Python application. The page makes asynchronous HTTP request to the application with [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). The application serves a 200 with proper JSON body. jQuery misinterprets the response as 404 and reloads the page? Is this above correct? Are you using the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview) to verify the requests/responses? What tells you it's receiving the 404?

Answer (score 2):

the server response with content-type: text\html and your ajax call expects json. you'll need to set the header of the response to Content-type: application/json. also you might try setting the headers of your ajax call to accept gzip encoded data.

in php you could do this

> header('Content-type: application/json');

before you echo the json. Or you could set the type of the ajax call to text, html.

also it is recommended to chain your callback functions with jquery like so

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/m/auth/login',
    headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip" },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',//be sure you are receiving a valid json response or you'll get an error
    data: {x: 'y'},
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(response);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: I tried to set content-type to application/json before and it doesn't matter, it's still 404. After all, when you set dataType: "json", jQuery ignores content-type.

Comment: try setting the headers to accept gzip encoded responses. updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I see in sniffer that request sent by jQuery is accepting gzip-encoded responses, co it has to be something else.