# 404 error because of ajax code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, http-status-code-404

I have a form with `action=""` and many AJAX codes to validate or chain-select the form elements as below.

** My current code (Simplified) **

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['create_transaction'] ) ) {
 // do something
}
?>

<div>
  <!-- period information will be filled up by ajax -->
  <input type="text" name="period" class="form-control" id="period" readonly />
</div>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <input name="r_date" type="date" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['r_date'] ) ? $_POST['r_date'] : date( "Y-m-d" ); ?>" class="transaction_date" />
  <input type="submit" name="create_transaction" value="Create" />
</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Do this and that...


  /*  Get period information if date is already filled up on page load */
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
  var $transaction_date = $(".transaction_date").val();

  if( $transaction_date ) {
    // call ajax for period <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM CHILD.
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: 'action=get_period_by_date&transaction_date='+$transaction_date,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(results) {
            jQuery("#period").val(results);
        }
    }); 
  }

});
</script>
```

Here I am retrieving a period name using the input date. For example, if the date is *2014-01-01*, then the `#period` div will be filled up with *PERIOD-01*. If the date is *2014-08-25*, then the `#period` div will be filled up with *PERIOD-08*. This date field is auto-filled up with today's date when the page loads.

The problem is that if I insert the AJAX code to retrieve period information using the date input, **submitting the form (clicking the 'create' button) leads to 404 error**. If I remove the code, the form works well.

There doesn't seem to be a problem in the `get_period_by_date` function since it correctly retrieves and shows period name.

What would be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Once you resolve the 404 error, you must use `.text()` or `.html()`, not `.val()`, to fill in a DIV.

Comment: I think it's meaningless use of ajax without place it inside any events. You can fetch that data directly from PHP in `input #period`.

Comment: Yes, I checked ajaxurl and it has correct url, and the ajax is functioning as designed...

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. What I need is to do is show the period name when users select a date (not when the date is submitted). How do I achieve this without using ajax?

Comment: If you want to do that when users select a date than you need to place it inside `change event` of that select element than ajax is useful.

Comment: Yes, I also have a code for that, too. When the page loads, r_date is filled with today's date. Later users can freely change the r_date. So I have two codes, one is triggered when r_date changes, and the other is the code in the above question.

Comment: Please clearly mention your question than it's being easy to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65746/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-dongsan).

Answer (score 1):

404 error means that your AJAX request leads to an unexisting path. Thats the first issue you should solve :).

Use your console to debug this one:

```
 var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
```

You are using this var in a jQuery method. I think it will be literally interpreted. I don't think it's possible to use php syntax here.

I'm not sure if it's a good practice, but for a quick fix you could make a hidden field in your html page with that tag. And then you could easily get the value from it with the use of jQuery or javascript

Comment: Yes, I checked that ajaxurl has a valid url by writting it into console. Also, this AJAX is working good since it correctly converts the input date into a period name and displays it in #period. However, when I submit the form, it doesn't go to the PHP function of if( isset( $_POST['create_transaction'] ) ) but instead displays 404 error...

Comment: console.log(ajaxurl) ? It seems odd for me. 
Anyhow, you could take a look at this one here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766803/jquery-ajax-get-post-request-returns-404-in-error-handler-but-valid-response-is